# Unclear Behaviour With `throw`and String Concatenation

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
const func = () => {
  throw new Error('hey') + 'boo'
  return 'OK'
}

try {
  const val = func()
  console.log(val)
} catch (error) {
  console.log(error)
}
```

When launched the result is a console line:
`"Error: heyboo"`

But this is not clear reading the code.
What's the reason for this?

Comment: You can use https://astexplorer.net/ to check the order of statement execution. Expand the tree on the right on the gist: https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/0f07cc101674630b2096e1b3278a32d6/4dc80c382bb34bdad0d617d0033c41cacd3028a7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you're doing `new Error('hey') + 'boo'` and throwing that (which may be surprising). Here's what the code is doing:

- Creates the error object
- Does `+` on the error object and `'boo'`, which converts the error object to string (`"Error: hey"`) and appends `"boo"` to it
- Throws the resulting `"Error: heyboo"` string

...which you then catch and display.

JavaScript is slightly unusual compared to other languages in that it lets you `throw` any value, including a string. You aren't restricted to throwing `Error` objects.

This code does the same thing, hopefully making it a bit clearer by breaking things into steps:

```js
const func = () => {
    // Create error
    const error = new Error("hey");
    // Append `"boo"` to it to get a string
    const str = error + "boo";
    // Throw the string
    throw str;
    // This is never reached
    return "OK";
};

try {
    const val = func();
    console.log(val);
} catch (error) {
   console.log(error);
}
```